# how to get gettext of a text view in getview method?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a listview populating using cursor in which custom row exist.  There are set of textviews in the row.  I also have a image view in the row.  I would like to set an image based on a value of the textview.  My code is

```
public class DisplayCards extends Activity {

    private Divyadesamdb dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pasuram);

        dbHelper = new Divyadesamdb(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        // Clean all data
        dbHelper.deleteAllPasurams();
        // Add some data
        dbHelper.insertPasurams();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String category = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_CATEGORY);
        String start = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_START);
        String ending = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ENDING);
        // Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        displayListView(category, start, ending);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void displayListView(String mcategory, String mstart, String mending) {
        String category = mcategory;
        String starting = mstart;
        String ending = mending;
        int rowsFound = 0;

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllPasurams(category, starting, ending);
        /*
         * How many rows returned from the query
         */
        rowsFound = cursor.getCount();

        // the desired columns to be bound

        String[] columns = new String[] {
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_PAASURAMNUMBER,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_AAYIRAM,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_AZHWAAR,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_CATEGORY,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_MANGALASASANAMON,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_PAASURAM_EN_STR,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_TITLE,
                Divyadesamdb.PASURAMS_COLUMN_TITLENUMBER };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvPaasuramNumber, R.id.tvAayiram,
                R.id.tvAzhwaar, R.id.tvCategory, R.id.tvMangalasasanamOn,
                R.id.tvPaasuram, R.id.tvSubCategory, R.id.tvTitle,
                R.id.tvtvTitleNumber };
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        // as well as the layout information
        MyCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.paasuram_single_item, cursor, columns, to, 0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    // extend the SimpleCursorAdapter to create a custom class where we
    // can override the getView to change the row colors
    private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // get reference to the row
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row
            // background

            // want to get the value of this text view,
            // but not getting handle. 
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) Context).getLayoutInflater();

            TextView azhwaarView = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textViewAzhwaar);

            String azhVal = azhwaarView.getText().toString();

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 233, 233));
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
            }
            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

not sure how to get the handle of textview.  Getting Null pointer exception.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

paasuram_single_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAzhwaar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Azhwaar"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nammalwar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivAzhwaar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivAzhwaar"
        android:text="TitleNumber"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHyphan1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvHyphan1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvHyphan1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHyphan1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAayiram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:text="Aayiram"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHyphan2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtvTitleNumber"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvAayiram"
        android:text=" - "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvHyphan2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvHyphan2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHyphan2"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHyphan3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvCategory"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvCategory"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCategory"
        android:text=" - "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvHyphan3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvHyphan3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHyphan3"
        android:text="SubCategory"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaasuram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAayiram"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvAayiram"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="paasuram"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaasuramNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvPaasuram"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvPaasuram"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="PaasuramNumber"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAzhwaar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvMangalasasanamOn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvMangalasasanamOn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPaasuram"
        android:text="Azhwaar"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMangalasasanamOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCategory"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPaasuram"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="MangalasasanamOn"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Image on each row is different based on the value of the textview.

Comment: Put your code in `getView()` of Custom Adapter of ListView.

Comment: try `TextView azhwaarView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAzhwaar);` instead of `view.getTag()`...

Comment: Code above is the custom adapter of listview

Comment: Tried TextView azhwaarView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAzhwaar); not working, same issue

Comment: You have to inflate a layout for your view. Check out LayoutInflater.

Comment: layout has been inflated... if I remove above code, all works well.

Comment: @user3059551 then post your xml file... I think there is no `TextView` in your layout with id `textViewAzhwaar`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the problem I have done the following:

1. created a table column with int datatype
2. got the R.drawable.xxx and stored the int to the database
3. retrieved the data and set to the image in the row level.

Thanks for all the help!  Appreciate every help rendered.  Big thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Only two errors are their:

```
1).You are not inflating any view here:
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_inflator_layout,parent,false);

        TextView azhwaarView = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textViewAzhwaar);

        String azhVal = azhwaarView.getText().toString();

        return view;
    }

2).You are not seting any text to textview ,thats y when you trying to get the text
 it gives null pointer.
```